# Yammer REST API Post Message issue

Tags: yammer

I am posting messages to Yammer from my java application using 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json API and I am facing issue with the message that is displayed on Yammer. All the message shows " **from Yammer Developer Center**" instead of the sender name. Please advise on how we can change this to actual user name

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4rsw.png

Answer (score 0):

This is intended. That part of the UI shows the application that the user posted a message from.

For example, it could say `from Android`.

The sender name is at the top of the post.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I fixed this issue and it is something to do with the client application setup on yammer.

Comment: @RangarajanB can you please help me with the solution